# Google Hangouts with 10.6.8 and Firefox 8.0.1

Tags: firefox, google

I've been trying to use **Google Hangouts** in **Firefox** for a few weeks, but Firefox keeps asking me to install a plugin. I've installed the required plugin more than once, but the page behaves as if I haven't installed it.

I've tried installing the plugin with Firefox running and without it running, and I've rebooted the computer several times. It never worked.

It works well in Google Chrome and Safari, but I prefer Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried **Google Hangouts** my self - and it works with my FF 8.0.1 on OS X Lion - using Google Talk plugin v2.5.6.4871

Comment: It makes sense. The question is... how do I debug/fix it? or at least why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: I've activated Google Talk plugin and now it works. I've found out due to your answer, although I didn't got it at first. Thanks.